# multi format in LabelField - BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, labelfield

I am placing text in a LabelField as multi-line. This is the method I am calling:

```
public void setFirstName(String fvalue,String lvalue,String date,String lastStatus) 
        {
            _fnameLabel.setText(fvalue+" "+lvalue+"\n"+date+"\n"+lastStatus);
            _fnameLabel.setFont((_fnameLabel.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 20, Ui.UNITS_px,
                    Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT)));
            _fnameLabel.setMargin(10, 0, 20, 0); //To leave some space from top and bottom
        }
```

I want different font (size,style etc) for each line. Is it possible to have multi-format in one labelfield. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with a `LabelField`, only with a [`RichTextField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html). You have to build arrays of offsets, fonts, and font indices to use for the field. It's a bit tedious, but not particularly hard. The method you want to use is

```
setText(String text, int[] offsets, byte[] attributes, Font[] fonts)
```

where:

- `offsets` is a sorted array of positions where formatting changes, including the start (0) and end (`text.length()`) of the text;
- `attributes` is an array of indexes into the `fonts` array, one for each text region (`offsets.length == attributes.length + 1`);
- and `fonts` is the array of different fonts you want to use.

The `attributes` array can contain the same value more than once, so `fonts.length` can be anything at all, as long as every element of `attributes` is a valid index of a non-`null` element of `fonts`.

Comment: Thank Ted for the reply. As I understand, offset is the position where the font change effect is to be specified. Considering I have a text:String richText = fvalue+"\n"+lvalue+"\n"+date+"\n"+lastStatus; 
int offsets[] ={0,5,richText.length()}; How should I specify position for the offset where the next position after "0" is the next line in the string?

Comment: It should be like `fvalue.length() + 1`, `fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + 2`, etc

Comment: @Sarah - If you want the first line to be in a different font, then the offset for the change should be after the `\n` that ends the first line, which would be (like Eugen said) `fvalue.length() + 1` (instead of `5` like you have now). If `fonts[0]` is the font for the first line and `fonts[1]` is the font for the rest of the text, then declare `byte[] attributes = {0, 1}`.

Comment: Thank for the pointers. I tried like this but it throws NullPointerException.
  String richText = fvalue+"\n"+lvalue+"\n"+date+"\n"+lastStatus;
  int offsets[] = {fvalue.length()+1, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + 2, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + date.length() + 3, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + date.length() + lastStatus.length() +4};
     byte attributes[] = {0,1,2,3}; I want to specify different font for each line.

Comment: @Sarah - Since your attribute indices go from 0 through 3, did you define four fonts in the `fonts` array?

Comment: yes I did: 
Font[] fonts = new Font[4];
     fonts[0] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 20, Ui.UNITS_px,Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT);
     fonts[1] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 14,Ui.UNITS_px,Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT);
     fonts[2] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.ITALIC, 10,Ui.UNITS_px,Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT);
     fonts[3] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 14, Ui.UNITS_px,Font.ANTIALIAS_STANDARD, Font.COLORED_OUTLINE_EFFECT);

Comment: @Sarah - If I counted correctly, `attributes.length == offsets.length`. You need to have one more offset than you have attributes (for the end of the text).

Comment: @Ted I added richText.length() as another parameter to offset:
int offsets[] = {fvalue.length()+1, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + 2, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + date.length() + 3, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + date.length() + lastStatus.length() +4, richText.length()};
     byte attributes[] = {0,1,2,3};
I still get NullPointerException. Can you please help.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You need to insert `0` as the first element of `offset`. Then eliminate the entry just before `richText.length()` (it is wrong anyway; it points past the end of your text). This will leave 5 elements in `offsets` and 4 elements in `attributes` as required.

Comment: @Ted, it does not work, I keep getting Null Pointer Exception. This is what I tried:
int offsets[] = {0,fvalue.length()+1, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + 2, fvalue.length() + lvalue.length() + date.length() + 3,richText.length()};
     byte attributes[] = {0,1,2,3};

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code and the exception?